# How to set an image properly as background?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set an image as a background but the zoom version of image is coming.

My code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

body, html {
  height: 100%;
}
.bg {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("../../media/image1.jpeg");

  /* Full height */
  height: 100%;

  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
</style>
</head>
<body class="bg">
</body>
</html>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure the image is big enough? When it's zoomed that usually means it wasn't big enough to fit the container so it got enlarged.

Comment: you could try to set `background-size: cover;` to `background-size: contain;` and see how it looks when not trying to cover the body, but maintain its own size

Comment: Your code is working just fine.? I just tested it. check your image resolution.

Comment: yes contain is working , thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can use the propertie background-size, here is a following guide:

**background-size: auto**

Default value. The background image is displayed in its original size:

```css
div{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:5px solid blue;
  background-image:url("https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/picture-element/images/kitten-small.png");
  background-size:auto;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

**background-size: lenght**
Sets the width and height of the background image. The first value sets the width, the second value sets the height. If only one value is given, the second is set to "auto". Read about length units

```css
div{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:5px solid blue;
  background-image:url("https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/picture-element/images/kitten-small.png");
  background-size:10px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

**background-size: percentage**

Sets the width and height of the background image in percent of the parent element. The first value sets the width, the second value sets the height. If only one value is given, the second is set to "auto"

```css
div{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:5px solid blue;
  background-image:url("https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/picture-element/images/kitten-small.png");
  background-size: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

**background-size: cover** >good answer for this question<

Resize the background image to cover the entire container, even if it has to stretch the image or cut a little bit off one of the edges

```css
div{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:5px solid blue;
  background-image:url("https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/picture-element/images/kitten-small.png");
  background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

**background-size: contain** >the best answer for this question<

Resize the background image to make sure the image is fully visible

```css
div{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:5px solid blue;
  background-image:url("https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/picture-element/images/kitten-small.png");
  background-size:contain;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

**background-size: initial**

Sets this property to its default value.

**background-size: inherit**

Inherits this property from its parent element.

[Source on background-size](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

[Suggestion on following up read](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp)

Comment: Nice answer. I think the only think missing is the `background-repeat` set to `no-repeat`. In the example using `background-size: contain` the tip of the ear of the cat shows in the bottom.